# Is preposition required before 'yesterday' in certain cases?

Tags: prepositions, time

Is the following sentence correct?

> Last saved by Rod yesterday at 6:15 PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking if it's grammatical, the answer is that it is. *At yesterday* and *on yesterday* are not possible in English (although *until yesterday*, *before yesterday* and *after yesterday* are).

Comment: This answer is technically correct but I have a feeling the internet is not entirely happy with this yet. I expect to see a lot of constructions like "Rod @ yesterday" and so on as the online culture looks for a more readable solution.